# HTTP request to get the Dataverse API Version Number

Tags: dataverse

Which dataverse HTTP request should I use to get the dataverse api version number?

Here I found "server/api/info/version":

[image: Dataverse Documentation]
[Dataverse Documentation](https://guides.dataverse.org/en/latest/api/native-api.html)

But it's returning me a 404:

[image: HTTP Get to obtain the Dataverse Version Number]

I was expecting to find one of the version numbers we see in the following link (ex:  9.2.23042.00116):
[Microsoft Dataverse Released Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/released-versions/microsoft-dataverse)

Answer (score 1):

You confused `Microsoft Dataverse` with `The Dataverse Project`.

For Microsoft Dataverse with the API you need to call the function `RetrieveVersion` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/reference/retrieveversion)

Because is a Function you can just do a GET to the endpoint:

/api/data/v9.0/RetrieveVersion()

If you are using Postman you need to be authenticated first.